# How to enable or add barear authentication in openfire for administrative rest api

Tags: java, openfire

Currently i am able to execute administrative rest api sucha as get users , chatroom (http://example.org:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users)  from client using basic authentication. is there any way to add barear authentication in openfire?

I have openfire java source code

https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire

Where we can add barear authentication in this code ? i dont have more knowledge in java.

Answer (score 2):

The Rest API from Openfire does not support Barear Auth, but Basic and Shared Secret key Authentication. You can find more here: https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/1.3.9/restAPI/readme.html#authentication

It is also possible to implement your own Authentication, but you have to implement that in JAVA.

Comment: REST API Plugin is an open source project. If you like, you can create an pull request to the project, with your changes.

Comment: I have modified this now

Comment: Feel free, to create a PR: https://github.com/igniterealtime/openfire-restAPI-plugin